# How to incorporate unnamed modules when using javapackager

Tags: java, java-module, javapackager

Trying to incorporate an unnamed module jar into another project.  When we run the javapackager command we are getting below error:

```
[exec] Creating app bundle: CoderDx in C:\workspace\DLL3MDebug\dist
[exec] Module artificialmedgui.coderdx does not exist.
[exec] "Adding modules: [artificialmedgui.coderdx] to runtime image."
[exec] Exception: java.lang.module.FindException: Error reading module: C:\workspace\DLL3MDebug\lib\cfintami.jar
[exec] Error: Bundler "Windows Application Image" (windows.app) failed to produce a bundle.
[exec] Result: -1
```

The unnamed module jar is cfintami.jar. This jar contains a single class in the default package.  It also contains the module-info.java.

Below is my project structure. The unnamed Java project is Dllcommunication.  The main project is DLL3MDebug.  Using Eclipse Photon and Java 10 on both projects.

Any help appreciated.

[image]